# getting event object while using input and output decorators on properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

While using the @input and @output decorators on properties, I am getting an event object as well as passing object on the output property and an event object replicates the passing object.

Here is the my code.

In Parent component is.

```
<example [focusOn]="focusOnExample" (change)="checkExampleData($event)"></example>

checkExampleData(example: any){   
    this.starSign = example;  
}
```

And my child component is

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (click)="isExampleClicked($event.target.checked)">

<input type="text" #myInput class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase"  formControlName="exxampleNo" [readonly]="!showHide"
                    (keyup)="formResponse(myForm)">



@Component({
    selector: 'example ',
    templateUrl: './child.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    public myForm: FormGroup;
    public showHide: boolean = true;
    public exampleData = {
        exampleValue: "",
        exampleValid: false
    }

    @Input() focusOn: boolean;
    @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.addValidationOnExample();        
    }

    addValidationOnExample() {
        this.exampleData .exampleValid = false;
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            panNo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10)]]
        });
        this.sendOutput(this.exampleData)
    }

    removeValidation() {
        this.exampleData.exampleValid = true;
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            panNo: []
        });
        this.sendOutput(this.exampleData);
    }

    isExampleClicked(value: boolean) {
        this.exampleData.exampleValue = "";
        if (value) {
            this.showHide = false;
            this.removeValidation();                                    
        } else {
            this.showHidePan = true;
            this.addValidationOnExample();
        }
    }

    formResponse(formData: any) {
        if (formData.valid) {
            this.exampleData.exampleValue = formData.value.exxampleNo;
            this.exampleData.exampleValid = formData.valid;
            this.sendOutput(this.exampleData)
        }else{
            this.exampleData.exampleValue = "";
            this.exampleData.exampleValid  = formData.valid;
            this.sendOutput(this.exampleData)  
        }
    }

    sendOutput(exampleData){
        this.change.emit(exampleData);
    }


}
```

While I check on the checkExampleData function in my parent component, I get both objects here (passing object and event object). This also emits the this.starSign value as an event object instead of exampleData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because you have used name `change` which is by default defined by angular for change events.

You must use some other name instead of `change`.

Comment: Welcome!! @Ricky

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, event.target.value

```
checkExampleData(example: any){   

        this.starSign = example.target.value;  
    console.log("value",this.starSign);
    }
```

That's all you got proper data.
Whenever use event you have to use event.target.value.

Let try this once and let me know.